# Saving a temporary managed object context on a background queue

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data, grand-central-dispatch, nsmanagedobjectcontext

According to the [Concurrency with Core Data Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html), you should not save a NSManagedObjectContext in a background thread, because it is possible for the app to quit before the save completes, since threads are detached.

If I'm understanding correctly, that means something like this is incorrect

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
    NSManagedObjectContext* tempContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    [tempContext setParentContext:[[MyDataManager sharedInstance] mainContext];
    [tempContext performBlockAndWait:^{
         //Do some processing
        NSError* error;
        [tempContext save:&error];
    }];
});
```

My first instinct would be to just save the context on the main queue when it's finished, but managedObjectContexts are supposed to be thread safe. Is the following something that would solve the problem or is there a better solution?

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
    NSManagedObjectContext* tempContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    [tempContext setParentContext:[[MyDataManager sharedInstance] mainContext];
    [tempContext performBlockAndWait:^{
        //Do some processing
    }];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [tempContext performBlockAndWait:^{
            NSError* error;
            [tempContext save:&error];
        }];
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First:

In your first example:
The `[context save:...]` should be done in the context's `performBlockAndWait:` block.
Also, if you are using a background context, you could simply call its `performBlock:` method, as it is already use GCD for dispatching, so it will look something like:

```
NSManagedObjectContext* tempContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
[tempContext setParentContext:[[MyDataManager sharedInstance] mainContext];
[tempContext performBlock:^{
    //Do some processing
    NSError* error;
    [tempContext save:&error];
}];
```

Secondly:

**"Saving in a Background Thread is Error-prone"** (as I know it and understand it) means:
You can save in the background, but it is NOT guaranteed that the save you called will run to completion if the application quit (the database would still be valid, or could be rolled back to a pre-partial-save state).
==>
If you use background save, don't assume that a save operation has completed between 2 application executions.

Thirdly (just to emphasise):
DON'T use a private-queue context without `performBlock:` or `performBlockAndWait:`
==>
Your second example will lead to unexpected behavior

Comment: Ok calling the save in performBlock makes sense, but is there a way to ensure the background save fully completes before the application quits?

Comment: As I mentioned in my second point, NO. That is the difference between a main-thread save and a background save. if you have critical information that must be saved, do it on the main thread.

Comment: Thanks, but my original question is how can I actually do that? You said my second example will lead to unexpected behavior. Is it because I didn't use performBlock or is it because it is a private queue context being executed on the main thread? Please see my edited question. What is the correct way to save on the main thread?

Comment: Your second example was wrong due to a save not done within the private-queue context `performBlock...` method. Your application might be terminated at any moment by the user without notice (in the background). this would mean that all saves that has not completed will not complete (event on the main thread). The reason you should save on the main thread is to give the user a consistent experience (the user performed an action with permanent effect, this should be reflected in the next application run ==> save on main thread)

Comment: Okay so my second example is now correct such that the save is executed on the main thread and will always finish?

Comment: The save will halt the main thread, but not necessarily be performed on it. From the user point of view, the action will be saved as if on main thread.

Comment: So if the user closes the app during the save, will the app wait for the save to complete before quitting, even though perfromBlockAndWait: performs the save on a separate thread? I don't care what thread it happens on as long as it always finishes.